# Show that $M$ is $not$ $connected$ if and only if there exists a non-constant continuous function $g$ : $M$ → ${0,1}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Show that $M$ is $not$ $connected$ if and only if there exists a non-constant continuous function $g$ : $M$ → {0,1} (the metric space containing just the numbers $0$ and $1$, with the relative metric from $R$).

My attempt: this is far out of reach I believe.

→
If there exists a non constant continuous function g with the conditions stated above, then M is not connected.
Taking the inverse image of {0,1}, I have  connected space $X_0$ and $X_1$.
Since they are disjoint and their union = M, then M is not connected.

The backwards implication I can't see to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $M$ is not connected. Then $M=X_0\cup X_1$, where $X_0$ and $X_1$ are *open*, *nonempty*, and *disjoint*. What can you say about the map $f(x)=0$ if $x\in X_0$, and $f(x)=1$ if $x\not\in X_0$?

Comment: That would imply that x is being sent to two different outputs, which means that it's not injective.

Comment: @MichaelCera I don't understand your comment at all. $f$ may not be injective, but that's not really relevant . . . Moreover, it is *not* the case that a single $x$ is being sent to two different outputs simultaneously, and even if that were true, that would mean that $f$ is not a function, not that $f$ isn't injective (injectivity = no two different *inputs* go to the same *output*).

Comment: sorry I mistook one to one for a second. To answer your question, it's saying that if f(x) =1 where x is not in X_1, then x must be in x_0

Comment: @MichaelCera Oops, this one was my fault - I had a typo in the definition of $f$. Look at it again - what can we conclude about $f$?

Comment: Then x must be in x_1

Comment: Yes, if $f(x)=1$ then $x\in X_1$. What about conversely - if $x\in X_1$, what is $f(x)$, and why?

Comment: Then for any x in X_1, f(x)=1 since all of these values get mapped to 1

Comment: Yes (note that you're using the fact that $X_0$ and $X_1$ are disjoint there). Finally, is $f$ continuous?

Comment: it has to be! I just realized I had forgotten to write that f is a non-constant continuous function.

Comment: Once you've proved all the things you've observed above - that $f$ sends $X_0$ to $0$, $X_1$ to $1$, is non-constant, is defined everywhere, and is continuous - then you've done the problem!

Comment: Thank you Noah! I guess my problem is showing that it's not constant. I can't seem to figure out weather that means that all of my values get sent to one place or not.

Comment: So $f$ is constant iff $f(x)=f(y)$ for every $x$ and $y$ - in this case, can you think of how to find an $x$ and a $y$ such that $f(x)\not=f(y)$?

Comment: I see what you mean. I very much appreciate you!