# Conneceted metric space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

First of all my english is not the best, so sorry for that.

I have math task: For a connected metric space $(M,d)$ there is no steady, non constant function $f:M \to \{ 0,1 \}$, when $\{ 0,1 \}$ the Hamming metric is.

So my problem is that I really don't know what my Professor want. We never learned something about the Hamming metric. He gave us also the Hint: Consider that the inverse images of 0 and 1 are completed under f.

Comment: $d(M,d)$ makes no sense.  What is $d$ used twice?

Comment: o thank im sry, it was my fail i edited

Comment: I think that in the usual English terminology you’re being asked to prove that if $\langle M,d\rangle$ is a **connected** metric space, there is no **continuous**, non-constant function $f:M\to\{0,1\}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete metric $d_0$: $d_0(0,0)=d_0(1,1)=0$, and $d_0(0,1)=d_0(1,0)=1$.

Comment: I think the hint is to consider the **inverse images** of $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ under $f$.  Note that both these sets are open (and closed) in $M$.

Comment: Yes this right, this is what i want to ask. Again im sorry for my Bad english i edited, so everybody understand IT. Thanks Mr Scott. Yeah i think IT means the inverse images i edited.

Comment: Hint: If such a function did exist, consider $f^{-1}(0) \cup f^{-1}(1)$, which is a disjoint open cover of X of non-empty, proper subsets...

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1534597/266110)